# Cannot access website in LAN. NAT Hairpinning in nftables

Tags: iptables, router, nat, nftables

I am trying to get NAT hairpinning working on my router. I cannot access my local website host on my LAN (192.168.1.3). I am using nftables with the following config:

enp1s0 = WAN
enp2s0 = LAN

```
#!/sbin/nft -f
flush ruleset
table ip nat {
        chain prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority -100; policy accept;
                iifname "enp1s0" tcp dport { 80, 443 } dnat to 192.168.1.3
                meta nftrace set 1
        }

        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
                ip saddr 192.168.1.0/24 ip daddr 192.168.1.3 tcp dport { http, https } counter snat 192.168.1.1
                oifname "enp1s0" masquerade
                meta nftrace set 1
        }
}
```

How exactly can I get hairpinning to work? I have seen people use split DNS but I am not too sure how to set that up.

Answer (score 1):

To do NAT Hairpinning in nftables you can add a DNAT rule which is checking if the destination address of the packages is the external ip of your network. You also need to do masquerading on the internal interface (LAN).

```
flush ruleset

define wan = enp1s0
define lan = enp2s0

define webserver = 192.168.1.3
define extip = 1.2.3.4

table ip nat {
        chain prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
                tcp dport { 80, 443 } ip daddr $extip dnat to $webserver
        }

        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                oif $wan masquerade
                oif $lan masquerade
        }
}
```

Comment: What if the "external ip" is dynamic?